# How to express the word "enjoy"? As in "enjoy traveling"

Tags: vocabulary

As a native english speaker, I've always struggled with the translation of "to enjoy" in to mandarin. I know that a couple of variations involve 享受， or 欣赏. But often the sentences I write using both of those feel unnatural. In this case, how would I say "If I don't sleep well tonight, I won't enjoy traveling tomorrow" 
Could I say

"如果我睡的不够我明天就不会享受我们的旅游"

Comment: I'm not a native Chinese speaker but I think the sentence is correct, except the wrong use of "的". You should use "得" instead (如果我睡得不夠).
But please wait the answer of a native Chinese speaker to have reliable information. ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with 'enjoy' as 享受. You don't feel natural because we don't say it that way. 要是我今晚睡不好，明天的旅行就玩不好/玩不尽兴。we prefer HAVE FUN than ENJOY.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Fox's correction in his comment, your sentence is correct.

欣賞 would not be the right word to use, however, since you mentioned it in your question. It refers more to a "viewable" enjoyment, like a picture.

To extend on Sean C.'s answer, a lot of times we don't say 享受 to express enjoyment. A simple example:

> I enjoy traveling to foreign countries. 我喜歡出國旅遊.

Notice how you don't say:

> 我享受出國旅遊

Because it would sound more like: "I lavish in foreign travels."

Answer (score 2):

While both 享受 and 欣赏 could means enjoyment, there are very few cases they are interchangable. 享受 is more likely oneself's feeling while 欣赏 is more about one's feeling toward others/other things. 欣赏 is mainly use for appreciation / admire.

Answer (score 1):

Both 享受 and 欣赏 are types of enjoy, and they do have different meanings and should be used in different context.

享受 can be though more of receiving an enjoyment, such as being pampered. It is often used when someone or something allows you to have your enjoyment.

欣赏 on the other hand is more of an admiration towards other things. For example, you can admire a piece of artwork, and enjoy the artwork.

In your sentence, you picked 享受 correctly, as you are not admiring anything in this context, but simply receiving from the trip/vacation. However, I would use 无法 over 不会. While in English, I won't sounds perfectly fine, in Mandarin, it sounds like you won't because you don't want to. If you said you can't instead of you won't, people will feel you are more polite and relate the cause to the lack of sleep instead of you not wanting to make an effort to enjoy the trip.